# Query XML with stylesheet/namespace included in the xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I have tried several ways to query this data out, but have not been successful. I am on SQL Server 2012. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <_x005B_M_x005D_._x005B_SEQID_x005D_ xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:short">200</_x005B_M_x005D_._x005B_SEQID_x005D_>
    <_x005B_M_x005D_._x005B_CPID_x005D_ xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">1002</_x005B_M_x005D_._x005B_CPID_x005D_>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: Also -- what's the root namespace for this document?

Comment: ...what queries have you attempted already? Show your work.

Comment: The only namespaces I see here are for `xs` and `xsi` prefixes, and your tags are not using either namespace prefix, so they should be entirely irrelevant.

Comment: This doesn't look like XML to me (where are the end tags?). Are you sure you have posted it correctly? If so, forget any idea of using XML-based tools to query it.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to have more details on what exactly you want to get out of this, but here is a start, assuming each Element of the XML represents a row:

```
DECLARE @SampleData XML = N'
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <_x005B_M_x005D_._x005B_SEQID_x005D_ xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:short">200</_x005B_M_x005D_._x005B_SEQID_x005D_>
    <_x005B_M_x005D_._x005B_CPID_x005D_ xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">1002</_x005B_M_x005D_._x005B_CPID_x005D_>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
';

DECLARE @Delim VARCHAR(50) = '._x005B_';
DECLARE @DelimLen INT = LEN(@Delim);

;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT  xrow.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS [ElementName],
           xrow.value('declare namespace xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; (./@xsi:type)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS [xsi:type],
           xrow.value('./text()[1]', N'VARCHAR(50)') AS [ElementValue]
   FROM    @SampleData.nodes('NewDataSet/Table/*') t(xrow)
)
SELECT *,
       SUBSTRING(
          cte.ElementName,
          CHARINDEX(@Delim, cte.ElementName) + @DelimLen,
          CHARINDEX('_',
                    cte.ElementName,
                    CHARINDEX(@Delim, cte.ElementName) + @DelimLen + 1) - 
                       (CHARINDEX(@Delim, cte.ElementName) + @DelimLen)
                   ) AS [RowType]
FROM cte;
```

Output:

```
ElementName                           xsi:type    ElementValue  RowType
_x005B_M_x005D_._x005B_SEQID_x005D_   xs:short    200           SEQID
_x005B_M_x005D_._x005B_CPID_x005D_    xs:string   1002          CPID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @demo xml = '<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <_x005B_M_x005D_._x005B_SEQID_x005D_ xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:short">200</_x005B_M_x005D_._x005B_SEQID_x005D_>
    <_x005B_M_x005D_._x005B_CPID_x005D_ xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">1002</_x005B_M_x005D_._x005B_CPID_x005D_>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>'

select t.r.value('(./*[local-name()=''_x005B_M_x005D_._x005B_SEQID_x005D_'']/text())[1]','integer') seqid
, t.r.value('(./*[local-name()=''_x005B_M_x005D_._x005B_CPID_x005D_'']/text())[1]','nvarchar(128)') cpid
from @demo.nodes('/*/*') t(r)
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21769